# Help with model averaged parameter estimates with aiccmodavg

Tags: aic, glmm

I am trying to compute model averaged parameter estimates using modavg from AICcmodavg but I am getting an error I don't understand. Here is an example:

```
    Cand.mod2 <- list()
    Cand.mod2[[1]] <- lmer(dC~(1|scientific_name) + (1|indv_plant_num), 
       plants.C3, REML=F)
    Cand.mod2[[2]] <- lmer(dC~(1|scientific_name) +part +(1|indv_plant_num), 
      plants.C3, REML=F)
    Cand.mod2[[3]]  <- lmer(dC~(1|scientific_name)+ part + plant_type + 
      (1|indv_plant_num), plants.C3, REML=F)
    Cand.mod2[[4]] <- lmer(dC~(1|scientific_name) + part + plant_type + 
        scale(prev_rain) + (1|indv_plant_num), plants.C3, REML=F)
    Cand.mod2[[5]] <- lmer(dC~(1|scientific_name)+ part + plant_type + 
         scale(prev_rain) + scale(prev_max) + (1|indv_plant_num), plants.C3, 
          REML=F)
    Modnames <- c("null",
              "part", 
              "part + growth form", 
              "part + growth form + prior rain", 
              "part + growth form + prior rain + maximum temp"
              )
    fullCtabSPran <- aictab(cand.set=Cand.mod2, modnames=Modnames)
    modavg(cand.set=Cand.mod2, parm="plant_typetree",modnames=Modnames)
```

Here is a summary of the fixed effect factor levels of the top models:

> Fixed effects:
>                    Estimate Std. Error t value
>   (Intercept)      -25.65263    1.55697 -16.476
>   partflower         0.82594    0.47239   1.748
>   partfruit          0.59563    0.27674   2.152
>   partgalls          0.66198    0.66210   1.000
>   partleaves        -0.57942    0.22179  -2.613
>   partpith          -0.47639    0.49025  -0.972
>   partsap            2.08547    1.04232   2.001
>   partvines         -0.27060    0.40649  -0.666
>   plant_typegrass   -4.33196    2.20308  -1.966
>   plant_typeherb    -4.63271    1.68382  -2.751
>   plant_typeliana   -3.01308    1.62293  -1.857
>   plant_typesedge   -4.72983    2.36452  -2.000
>   plant_typeshrub   -4.70160    1.66360  -2.826
>   plant_typetree    -2.67433    1.59394  -1.678
>   scale(prev_rain)  -0.25257    0.07596  -3.325

I have no problem getting model averaged parameter estimates for the 'part' factor levels, or the 'rain' one, but when I try to get 'plant_type' ones I get this error:

> Error in modavg.AIClmerMod(cand.set = Cand.mod2, parm = "plant_typetree", modnames = >Modnames) :
>
> Some models include more than one instance of the parameter of interest. 
>   This may be due to the presence of interaction/polynomial terms, or variables
>   with similar names:
>       see "?modavg" for details on variable specification and "exclude" argument

I understand the exclude argument (I think) but I don't have any interaction terms and if there is a problem with names why doesn't the error also arise for the other factors.
What else could I be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the modavg.effect() function? The birds example in this link will help: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AICcmodavg/versions/1.33/topics/modavg.effect.